# Visualize graph network with more than 30k edges

Tags: visualization, graphs, social-network-analysis

I have a dataset with users connection and I want to create a directed network graph.

Nodes: ~20.000
Edges: ~33.000

I used to work before on NodeXL and Gephi, but now I am on Mac and I don't have access on NodeXL.

I tried Gephi and another tool called Cytoscape. Both of them were lagging and I could barely do some statistics. Visualizing the graph was a dream.

Is there any software (or maybe Python library) that can handle such a big network Graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes There are!

### [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)

I think 20k-30k node-edge would be OK on Networkx, IF YOU HAVE A GOOD MACHINE! Networkx is a great library in Python particularly for Graph Analysis so you have access to great analysis tools beside visualizing but visualizing 20k vertices needs much RAM and takes long.

### [Igraph](http://igraph.org/redirect.html)

Igraph is another great tool for Graph Analysis with APIs in Python, R and C. You can do a lot with Igraph library including nice plotting facilities.

### [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/)

SNAP was developed by Jure Leskovec and his colleagues at Stanford. A large scale graph processing library natively written in C with API in Python. This library can handle huge graphs on a single personal machine.

- **PS.1** Both of these guys have interfaces with different graph softwares like Gephi, etc.
- **PS.2** For large graphs I strongly recommend to work in C++ if you can. Speaking as a Network/Graph guy, C++ solves many problems out there!

Answer (score 1):

### [Mathematica's Graph Drawing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GraphDrawingOverview.html)

Mathematica can draw both 2D ([GraphPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html)) and 3D ([GraphPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot3D.html)) graphs (static and interactive) and has a host of options available to fine tune the display and interactive content.  There is a very detailed [Graph Drawing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GraphDrawingOverview.html) language overview that has tutorials and examples through out.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered in StackOverflow. [Visualizing a graph with a million vertices](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/812/visualizing-a-graph-with-a-million-vertices?rq=1)
. I would recommend use Graphexp for visualization with JanusGraph  as a back-end storage